# No one holds the lock but still thread awaits

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I have a particular scenario where my app UI freezes, when I take the process dump I can see that the UI thread is acquiring the lock and awaiting

```
OS Thread Id: 0x27f4 (0)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
000000000027b470 0000000076de177a [GCFrame: 000000000027b470] 
000000000027b5a8 0000000076de177a [GCFrame: 000000000027b5a8] 
000000000027b558 0000000076de177a [HelperMethodFrame: 000000000027b558] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
```

But at the same time !syncblk reveals that there are only wait-ers but no one is holding the lock (MonitorHeld is 2)

```
Index         SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info          SyncBlock Owner
 2888 00000000200adbc8            2         0 0000000000000000     none    0000000003c167d0 System.Collections.Hashtable
```

The problem I see is that the legacy code is acquiring lock on a hashtable and updating itself, but i do not see how can we await when no one is holding the lock?

The process dump was taken on a 64 bit machine and the process is a 64 bit process, my dev box is also 64 bit machine with 64 bit windbg

**[Update]**
When I use !mlocks (sosex extension) I see it shows totally different lock, which is a TCP Connection.

Comment: Is it possible that the lock is being locked/unlocked in different, incompatible ways? Maybe the legacy code isn't alerting the waiting thread when it releases the lock.

Comment: the legacy code is also .net module, and uses lock(hashtable) to release the monitor

Comment: Not using private lock objects is a very common way to cause deadlock.

Comment: I totally agree and understand that lock(this) and likes can cause such issues, but then how do i trace which other thread is holding the lock, the way i see it syncblk is reporting wrong

Comment: Please find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825477/how-can-net-threads-be-waiting-on-a-syncblk-which-is-not-owned-by-any-thread